# The size of a QWidget is limited. How can I change it?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt5.2

[image: application]

I want to build a Qt5.2 Application in C++ with Visual Studio 2013. I apply the `QWidget::resize` function to set the size of the QWidget object in the image above to 1200*800. But it seems that the QWidget object can't be that large(there are vertical and horizontal scroll bars).

How can I get the size of the QWidget object expanded to 1200*800 and remove the scroll bars? And how can I get the object at the centre of the application both vertically and horizontally?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a minimal example of what's going on. We shouldn't have to guess.

All I can see is up to three widgets: the top level one, the `QScrollArea`, and whatever widget is inside of the scroll area. If that's the case, then the scroll area is not managed by a layout, and when you resize the top level widget, the scroll area's size remains unchanged.

I see two solutions, assuming that `MyContentsWidget` is the widget that draws your genetics thingamajingy (if that's what it is).

1. Get rid of the toplevel widget and use the `QScrollArea` as a toplevel widget:

   ```
   int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     QScrollArea area;
     MyContentsWidget contents;
     area.setWidget(&contents);
     area.show();
     return app.exec();
   }
   ```
2. Add a layout to the toplevel widget, so that it'll resize the scroll area appropriately:

   ```
   class MyWindow : public QWidget {
     QGridLayout m_layout;
     QScrollArea m_area;
     MyContentsWidget m_contents;
   public:
     MyWindow(QWidget * parent = 0) : QWidget(parent), m_layout(this) {
       m_layout.addWidget(&m_area, 0, 0);
       m_area.setWidget(&m_contents);
     }
   };
   ```

In both cases, the order of declaration is the opposite of the order of destruction, and it is important since you must ensure that `MyContentsWidget` is destructed before the scroll area.

Answer (score 0):

Add your widget to QLayout:

```
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(widget);
mainWindow->setLayout(layout);
```